# What is the correct syntax for an html helper used by a strongly typed view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a stongly typed view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IPagedList<Product>>" %>
```

I'm trying to use an HTML helper on it that works fine on a non-strongly typed view.  I've tried a few variations, such as:

```
public static string Pager(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    //works great from non-strongly typed views
    return "Pager";
}

public static string Pager1<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper)
{
    //might work for a stongly typed view?
    return "Pager1";
}
```

Tried:

```
<%=Html.Pager() %>
<%=Html.Pager1() %>
<%=Html.Pager1<IPagedList<Product>>() %>
```

I get similar messages:

```
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<WillowCore.Common.IPagedList<Willow.Domain.BI.Product>>' does not contain a definition for 'Pager1' and no extension method 'Pager1' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<WillowCore.Common.IPagedList<Willow.Domain.BI.Product>>' could be found
```

What is the correct syntax?

[This is under MVC2 RC]

Answer (score 0):

rookie mistake -- just forgot to import my namespace in the web.config.

for the record, either work:

```
<%=Html.Pager1() %> 
<%=Html.Pager1<IPagedList<Product>>() %>
```